# Prevent inline-block element from expanding outside of container

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<td>
    <div class="long-line">
        <a>Some text</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

and css:

```
.long-line {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And I have two scenarios, I can solve one or the other, but not both.

**Scenario 1)** The div should not expand outside of the td and all extra text is cut off with ellipsis. This currently works.

**Scenario 2)** The div should NOT fill the td if it does not need to. In other words, if there is a small amount of text it does not take up any additional space that it does not need.

I can solve **Scenario 2** by adding ***display:inline-block*** to the class but once I do so, it breaks **scenario 1** by overflowing out of the td. Additionally, I tried adding *text-overflow:ellipsis* to the table cell and it does not do anything.

Is there a way to prevent the *inline-block* element from expanding out of it's container?

Any different approaches I should try instead?

Comment: how did you style your td

Comment: @KenKwok the td has no style added to it. I tried adding both text-overflow and overflow styles to it but they do not accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cygg0jb5/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="td">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    hello world!
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="td">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    hello world! hello world!
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline;
    background-color: red;

}

.td {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is, the outer div is filling the entire td now. Which is what I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/xmymt0xm/) what you want?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="long-line">
                <a>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="long-line">
                <a>loream ipsum </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.long-line {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:pink;
    max-width:200px;
}
td{
    border-style:solid;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Sort of. It accomplishes what I want in one particular spot but I cannot define a width on the class because it is widely used throughout the application.

Comment: I dont know if this is possible. Maybe you could alter the behaviour by using id identifier or you may set td max-width as 200px and remove the inline-block display on long-line but the div would then occupy the whole td.